# Can you use a mediaelement to render a live http TV stream?

Tags: windows-8, mediaelement, windows-8.1

Can you use a mediaelement in a Windows App to render a live TV stream?
The stream is being delivered as a HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Just pass URL as source of `MediaElement`.

```
<MediaElement Source="http://myurl.com/test.mp4"/>
```

Comment: Should work, but it depends on audio and video codec of the stream!

Comment: Thanks, that works with Win8.1 but did not work on my Win8.
It also only works when my server sends a transcoded ASF stream.  

Can I get raw data to display that is not compressed?